# Cloud Firestore not working only on iOS | Flutter

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to add to my flutter app services like firebase and Firestore.

I've already done this on windows, now I am on Mac.
I followed the official guide at this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add_flutterfire_plugins)

When I build the android app it works fine, but on iOS I keep getting errors like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZOQU.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Already tried to disable 'Use map Header' option, and to boot on legacy emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following configuration for Firestore in iOS:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.1+3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10
  # other dependencies
```

execute the following command:

```
flutter pub get
```

Download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, and copy it to the path `nameApp/ios/Runner`

Update Firebase with the command: `pod update Firebase`

**NOTE:** at some point in a project I had problems with firestore and what I had to do was the following, execute command `flutter clean`

in the following link it can be a video on youtube where they make an explanation of the firebase configuration for iOS [link](https://youtu.be/WIG4TxLYQk0?t=445)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I installed graph library from POD, then done your procedure and it works! Thanks a lot